# xcode Segue / container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, segue

I currently have a table view with all my cell names which when clicking on a specific cell you will be directed to that page with the use of a segue between the two to keep them linked, which is fine for example click the Hello cell and the hello page will be displayed. I have a label linked within the second view controller to match the cells name when loaded so that it only loads content specific to that cell. Now I'm attempting to add an embedded  container view within my second view and I want it to work in the same way. For example person click Hello cell, Hello view controller appear and content within container is relevant to that cell as well. Currently the label inside the main view controller controls what content goes in, how would I got about adding a label within the container view controller with the same concept. (Second view controller and container view controller should have same label title when cell clicked)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at prepareForSegue and passing a parameter property that way. Then in the destination view controller you can parse that and switch content based on it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSeguePerforming/prepareForSegue:sender:

Comment: A quick question at the moment I have table view controller to another view controller  but can I link the table view when clicked to go to both view controllers at the same time if so how?

Comment: One is the child of the other, correct? Link to the parent and then have the parent instantiate the child.

Comment: How would go about doing this? I very new to this.